# Wordpress Woocommerce: Set quantity BEFORE add to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What I want to do is have a dropdown/text box for quantity *before* the user clicks **add to cart**.

My goal is to have the quantity already set when the product goes into the cart; the user cannot modify the quantity of a product already in the cart for certain reasons (business process).

Woocommerce **add_to_cart_url()** only takes the product ID.

Does anyone have any experience in doing something similar to this?

Comment: The single product page has a quantity selector, so selecting quantity before clicking 'add to cart' is default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an override folder hierarchy within **wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php**.

You can find more details [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/). It works perfectly.

Thanks!